# Rotate object related to center

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Here's the thing, I have a cannon in my game that I want to be able to turn using my finger. I want the tip to always point in the opposite direction of where the finger is dragging off to, i.e. the tip should be pointing to the upper right if the finger is dragged to the lower left.

I just cant figure out how to get this to work. I've managed to get it to rotate using the following code:

```
local function rotateObj(event)
    local t = event.target
    local phase = event.phase

    if (phase == "began") then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
        t.isFocus = true

        -- Store initial position of finger
        t.x1 = event.x
        t.y1 = event.y

    elseif t.isFocus then
        if (phase == "moved") then
            t.x2 = event.x
            t.y2 = event.y

            angle1 = 180/math.pi * math.atan2(t.y1 - t.y , t.x1 - t.x)
            angle2 = 180/math.pi * math.atan2(t.y2 - t.y , t.x2 - t.x)
            print("angle1 = "..angle1)
            rotationAmt = angle1 - angle2

            --rotate it
            t.rotation = t.rotation - rotationAmt
            print ("t.rotation = "..t.rotation)

            t.x1 = t.x2
            t.y1 = t.y2

        elseif (phase == "ended") then

            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            t.isFocus = false
        end
    end

    -- Stop further propagation of touch event
    return true
end
cannon:addEventListener("touch", rotateObj)
```

While this does allow me to rotate my cannon, it doesnt keep the tip relational to where I'm dragging. I have no idea where to even go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my code.

I also created a game like yours but you control a bow and arrow.

```
function getAngle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    local PI = 3.14159265358
    local deltaY = y2 - y1
    local deltaX = x2 - x1

    local angleInDegrees = (math.atan2( deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / PI)*-1

    local mult = 10^0

    return math.floor(angleInDegrees * mult + 0.5) / mult
end

local arrow = display.newImage("wind_arrow.png")
arrow.x = display.contentWidth/2
arrow.y = display.contentHeight/2
arrow.touch = function(self, event)
    print(event.phase)
    if event.phase == "moved" then
        --If your image is originally pointing to the north use +90
        --If your image is originally pointing to the east use +180
        --If your image is originally pointing to the south use +270
        --If your image is originally pointing to the west use +360 or +0

        --My wind_arrow.png is point to the east so I use +180
        --You can use this formula
        arrow.rotation = (getAngle(arrow.x,arrow.y,event.x,event.y)+180)*-1
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch",arrow)
```

Comment: Thanks! This did exactly what I wanted. Not only is this code a lot smaller than my original code, but its also very easy to use. Much obliged!

Comment: Actually, I noticed one little error... The cannon now moves whenever I touch the screen, not just when I touch the cannon. Is there any way I could get this to work only if the user touches the cannon?

Comment: I should really start to figure things out myself first, THEN ask questions. This was easily fixed by changing the runtime event listener to: cannon:addEventListener("touch", cannon)

Answer (score 0):

look your first if elseif sentence.

```
if (phase == "began") then
    t.isFocus = true
elseif t.isFocus then
    XXX
end
```

it wouldn't work,when phase == "began",because if elseif sentence will enter to one path.
in your if,you set t.isFocus to true,but it will not be judged immediately in the elseif path.